# Can i use deep learning in my agriculture PHD?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

My PHD is about yield of soybeans and it is typical agriculture theme, but I am pretty good with programming and Python programming language and I have already some deep learning programs which I made by myself successfully. Problem is that model is not very easy to show on the paper.

Can I show model just like a chart or graph? And maybe somebody already solved issue with transporting deep learning model file to "paper"? Is it normal to use deep learning in my agriculture PHD instead common middle age Linear Regression etc?

Inputs and outputs is ok on paper but deep learning model is a little bit controversial in my scientific circles and I don't know how to present it so I'm asking maybe somebody already has successful experience by presenting deep learning model on the paper in science.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I do not understand your stated problem. Why is it not easy to show on paper? What are your inputs and outputs?

Comment: problem is that model in linear regression i can show like a equation, but in deep learning model located in the file

Comment: Inputs and outputs is ok on paper but deep learning model is a little bit controversial in my scientific circles and i don't know how to present it so i'm asking maybe somebody already has successful experience by presenting deep learning model on the paper in science. In worst case i will close question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please note that the following is my personal opinion; I still hope that you find it useful.

If you cannot properly explain a concept on paper, then it should not be part of your PhD thesis. It is possible to implement Deep Learning algorithms without any conceptual knowledge. While this may be (somewhat) acceptable in the industry, it will get you into trouble in academia.

I have no doubt that your algorithms are well-programmed and solve many issues that are challenging from a programmer's perspective. But that is not what the reviewers of your thesis are interested in. They are also not interested in the prediction accuracy of your algorithm. 
As scientists, they want to know *why* something happens; and to my knowledge, Deep Learning algorithms provide next to nothing on this question.

And this is where 'middle age' linear regression has its strengths (by the way: a quick way to make an enemy is to tell him that the method he has been using all his life is too old to be useful). Yes, linear regression is unexciting, and it has many shortcomings. But it is extremely well understood. Most importantly, there are tons of books and papers about the connection between *assumptions* and *valid interpretations*: we know under which assumptions and in which sense the linear regression estimator is optimal; we know which assumptions lead to which kind of confidence intervals for the estimator; we know about robustness with respect to model misspecification; etc.

As long as you cannot address these issues convincingly and on paper (That is: In what sense is my result optimal? How confident can I be about my result? How robust is my model?), you should not use Deep Learning in research as an alternative to classical statistical methods.